# An example using EXSLT func:script in Firefox

Tags: firefox, xslt, exslt

Can anyone point me to an actual complete example of using EXSLT func:script in a xslt file that works on Firefox (so if my XML file had a xml-stylesheet instruction it would transform the xml file into HTML using an external js file)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible as the XSLT processor implementation in Mozilla/Firefox does not support that EXSLT feature. The only EXSLT features supported by Mozilla are listed on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/EXSLT.